# Does electrical current have a measurable momentum?

Tags: superconductivity

If I were to build a levitating super-cooled superconducting loop of wire with a electrically charged circuit that would discharge its stored energy to produce a large circulation of current around the superconducting loop levitating off the ground, would the loop of wire experience a counter torque, forcing the loop to rotate in the opposite direction that the electrical current rotates to have a total torque and angular momentum equal to zero? Is this experiment possible?

Comment: Current means moving energy, thus moving mass, thus it has some momentum. Maybe it is even measurable. But it is far too small for any practical usage.

Comment: Yes, electric currents and the electric and magnetic fields associated with them do carry linear and angular momentum.  If you have access to Griffith's E&M book, see chapter 8.  [Here is a discussion by Feynman](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html), which I haven't actually read yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is the experiment possible, a version of the experiment at the atomic level was done by Einstein and de Haas[1].  Einstein and deHaas showed that the angular momentum inhering in the aligned electron spins in a ferromagnet can be exhibited on a macroscopic scale when the sample is demagnetize.  Apparently, his is the only experiment Einstein ever performed himself[2].

References
1.  Einstein and de Haas paper[pdf]
http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00012546.pdf

1. Wikipedia on the Einstein de Haas effect
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect

Comment: While this is a great experiment, it's a measurement of spin angular momentum, which is quite different from mechanical angular momentum.  Also interesting is that Einstein et al. got the wrong result by a factor of two, failing to discover the Landé g-factor, which Peter Galison discusses at length in *How Experiments End*.  In a superconductor the charge carriers are Cooper pairs of electrons which have zero net spin, but the magnetic fields the produce still carry linear and angular momentum.

Comment: The experiment was done for superconductors as well and showed similar results.  See
Pry, Lathrop, Gyromagnetic Effect in a Superconductor, Phys. Rev., 86, (1952), 905